# SharePoint 2013 unauthorized error c# console application

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I can access a SharePoint site on my company network via a browser passing in specific username and password however when I try to access the same site via my console application I get a 401 Unauthorized error.

I cannot use windows authentication for the logged in user due to the way our SharePoint security is set up and I have no control to change its settings.

Can anyone help me spot the issue?

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(doc.DocumentUrl);
request.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(spUser.username, spUser.Pwd, spUser.domain);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: what is DocumentUrl, the url of the site?

Comment: Yes its the url of the Sharepoint site im trying to access.